# Read statuses of a Facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Currently in my Android Application I'm using RSS Feed to display news.As I want to display more number of news, I'm planning to pull data from Facebook using Oauth. How can I pull data from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook docs with code examples for Android: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed

About Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/